# Order by date a list with multiple dates

Tags: node.js, sql-order-by, sequelize.js

I am building a page where I display a list of events. Each of the events takes place in one or two consecutive dates. The issue is that these events should be order by these dates.
I use Sequelize.js.

For example: 
event1  - in 13th and 14th of July should be displayed before the event2- in 10th and 11th of July because it the most recent one.

I have two tables: Events and EventDates with a one-to-many relationship.

```
 Event.findAll({ 
        include: [
            { model:EventDates, order: [ [ 'date', 'DESC' ]] },                  
        ],

    })
```

This will only order the two dates of one event, but will not compare the dates of different events.

How can I perform the operation of order?

EventDates model:

```
var EventDates= sequelize.define('eventdates', {    
  date: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE
  },
  availabletickets: {
   type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },
},
{
  freezeTableName: true
});
```

And the Events model:

```
var Event = sequelize.define('event', {
  title: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  slug: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
   description: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  isDeleted:{
   type: Sequelize. BOOLEAN,
   defaultValue: false
  },

}
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your current code your are ordering only inside Eventdates, you have to to order the whole list too:

```
Event.findAll({ 
        include: [
            { model:EventDates, order: [ [ 'date', 'DESC' ]] },                  
        ],
        order: [[ EventDates , 'date', 'DESC']]

    })
```